# Trivial linear algebra issue (octave/matlab)

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix of weights, and another matrix of data values. Can I multiply or divide one matrix by the other such that each element in one matrix is multiplied/divided only by the corresponding element in the other matrix, without having to loop through every position?

I feel ridiculous asking this question but I can't seem to find the answer via google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a .* b to multiply the matrices pointwise.

a ./ b to divide.

Like this:

```
octave:1> a = [1 2; 3 4];
octave:2> b = [3 4; 5 6];
octave:3> a .* b
ans =

    3    8
   15   24

octave:4> a ./ b
ans =

   0.33333   0.50000
   0.60000   0.66667
```

For an arbitrary binary function, use `bsxfun`:

[in octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/bsxfun.html)

[in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html)

Comment: hey, I have another question: suppose I want to multiply each column of a matrix by a corresponding scalar from a vector? Like if in your example I just wanted to multiply the first column of a by b_11 and the second column by b_12

Comment: its called matrix dot-multiplication. Google it out first.

Comment: @mavix: `bsxun(@times, a, b)` for multiplication (replace with `@rdivide` for division)

Answer (score 0):

A = [1 2 3];
B = [ 1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3];

C = repmat(A', 1,3)
ans = C *. B

Answer (score 0):

You want to use elementwise multiplication or division. To use elementwise multiplication (as opposed to matrix multiplication), put a period in front as such:

```
A .* B
```

Here is a tutorial on linear algebra with Octave (goes into a bit more depth): http://www.lauradhamilton.com/tutorial-linear-algebra-with-octave